# Implementing Slide Menu In App With Existing Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, menu, navigation-drawer

I have developed an app. So far without Slide Menu. I've searched for slide menus and [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) seems to be what I need. But the problem is that I am using Activities not Fragments. **Do I need to convert them into Fragments?** - I know there are some tricky way to tackle the issue maintaining Activities but I prefer the right one.

Is it normal approach that one ('mother') Activity will process everything using different Fragments?

And one childish question - Are all those apps (Facebook, YouTube, LinkedIn and other less know ones) with Slide Menus using Fragments? It turns out Activity's not so necessary now?
Every input (answer, link, comment) much appreciated

Comment: I faced the same question when I started this, but i stick to Activities & successfully implemented your asked scenario, I wrote a base class with drawer & main layout view as container & extend other activities with it, i wrote a method in base class which setcontentVeiw & in every child class I override that method & in this method's argument I pass child class's layout, so in this way I   got a replica of fragments being replaced in the same container.

Comment: As you said the right way to do this is using Fragments. For all my recent apps I've done the same thing you describe, almost all the time I have a MainActivity to hold the "core" and if I have some special action as video record or something like that I create an activity for this.

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper in this case you kind of lose all the benefits from the fragment manager don't? I'm not defending any option here, just a simple question

Comment: What I defined is for a very huge App, converting activities to fragments in major apps is not an easy one. O yes of course this type of projects starting from scratch must be with Fragments.

Comment: Thank you guys for helpful answers. If anyone answers one or two other questions from above I will accept it.

Comment: I'd like to know answer for 'childish' question :))

Comment: 99 times out of 100 they would be using Fragments now.

Comment: Why I stick with Activity, only reason is, in fragment the handling of backPress is  a serious ask & when you have Products then sub products  & inner sub products, while in Activity complexity level is much easier then Fragments.

Comment: Normally I just override the onBackPressed and with a simple validation (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() >0 ) I decide if I will call popBackStack to revert to the previous fragment or close the app, in some special cases I also force the back stack to be clean so the user can't return to the previous fragment (normally when the fragment was called from the sliding menu I do this, for that you just need to pop the back stack using the POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE in the parameters)

Comment: @GhostDerfel You do the perfect thing, only ask is complexity

Comment: @levi in Short(now which does't seems to be :) ) for a big developed Apps you can do work arounds with Activities, Otherwise a wise suggestion would be Fragments.

Comment: @SmartphoneDeveloper Yeah, I start converting my Activities into Fragments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating Fragments. It is correct way and it is easy. You will have no problems even if you have to add lots of Fragments to you app handled by a single Activity. It's clean and smooth. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer is no. You can use the Navigation Drawer witthout fragments(which I don't recommend). Just put your views inside a FrameLayout and that's it. Here's the code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mainContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ></FrameLayout>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/drawerList"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:background="#C3C4C5"
    ></ListView>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I just suggested this in the comments.

Comment: So, it is not recommended because benefits of FragmentManager are lost, right? any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

U can check [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). i use this sliding menu library to create side menu in my projects. This library is so powerful to create side menu and easy to use. Hope this help